# Get all elements listed in a pivot table filter (page field) with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to print a PDF output for each name in the page field list (highlighted in the image below). It shouldn't be the best approach, but I thought I'd get the list with all the available names and go filtering with a vba loop.

[image]

```
For Each Item In pvt.PivotFields("[LANC].[NAME].[NAME]").VisibleItemsList
    Debug.Print Item
Next
```

The problem that only works by selecting n-1 from the n elements in the list. If you select all, the field is set to "all" and VisibleItemsList returns an empty element.

Comment: there is a showpages method you can combine with a loop for printing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.showpages

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. Returns error 1004, showpages method failed.

Comment: It is a valid method. Check you are applying it correctly to the right pivot and that you have the appropriate page filter set up. I don’t know if there are restrictions on how many filters you can have in the page area. Check that as it may only allow the one.

Comment: In the method documentation, it is said to be incompatible with OLAP data sources. How can I check this? My pivot table is configured to store data model. May have relationship?